# Laravel - How can i filter a many to many model, where the relationship is absent by further columns?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So i have this situation, where a User can be assigned many Products, and a product can have many Users. So M-M relationship.

I can use the below, to get all products the user does not have (think of it as all products not assigned to this user):

```
$products = Product::whereDoesntHave('users', function($query) use ($user) {
                $query->where('uid', $user->id);
            });
```

However, now i added a new column to the products table called status. I want to adapt the above query so it gets me all products user does not have (same as above), but in addition only if this products status value is not equal to 1. So it can be 0 or Null. I tried the below, but it doesnt work (still shows products with status of 1).

```
$products = Product::where('status', 0)->orWhereNull('status')->
            whereDoesntHave('users', function($query) use ($user) {
                $query->where('uid', $user->id);
            });
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a closure to the `where` clause to group the status conditions together.

```
$products = Product::where(function ($query) {
  $query->where('status', 0)->orWhereNull('status');
})->whereDoesntHave('users', function($query) use ($user) {
  $query->where('uid', $user->id);
})->get();
```

Comment: That works, thanks a lot. So just to help my understanding the closure just puts the where part into brackets?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. If you look at the raw output SQL you'll see them grouped.